# .NET CORE 2.1.1 with Entity Framework Core 2.1.4 Code First: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a Extension Method to seed my table after created:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasData(
                new Event() { id = 1, WhenDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1) }
            )
    }
}
```

I created migration file with this command

> Add-Migration InitialCreate

and then

> Update-Database

to create database with table but I have this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

in my InitialCreate file I have this line:

> WhenDate = table.Column(type: "datetime", nullable: false)

in my console log, in insert into command, I see this character string:

> '2019-03-12T16:09:33.617+01:00'

I guess the string format is not correct, but how to change it? And what is the right format?

Thanks

Comment: What type is "WhenDate" in your AppUser class? DateTime?

Comment: yes "WhenDate" is DateTime type. When I copy/past insert into command in SSMS the error is the same but when I remove "+01:00" it woks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, if I replace `Now` by `UtcNow` it works ! Because it remove "+01:00"...

replace

> DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)

by

> DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1)

string result:

> '2019-03-12T17:08:25.682Z'

Answer (score 0):

For me, this occurs when I tried to alter column after running **update-database**:

I fixed by added manual default value like:
**defaultValue:"0001-01-01"**

For example:

```
  migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "OperationDateTime",
                schema: "DefinitionContext",
                table: "Path",
                type: "DateTime",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue:"0001-01-01");
```